# Resurrecting (reopening) an old question on art vs. technical skill

Tags: discussion

I'd really like to see

[Can one make good photographs with artistic sense but little real technical skill?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14361/can-one-make-good-photographs-with-artistic-sense-but-little-real-technical-skil)

reopened. I edited the original a little bit, and I think that while it's a "soft" question it is very answerable and interesting. I voted to reopen a while ago but apparently didn't get enough attention at that point, so I'm making an appeal here.

Comment: I agree, so I gave it my vote.

Comment: I also agree that this is very answerable and very valuable for anyone starting out in photography and trying to figure out if it is for them.  What portions of photography are art and what the limitations are without technique are fairly concrete and reasonably easily describable in a meaningful, but general way.

Answer (score 1):

I like these types of questions, at least as Community Wiki, because they can be really interesting.

However, the original question was rambling and without a real point. You've improved it, but I still think it's rambling and vague.  All that lead-up to the question about technical vs artistic: he mentions not being able to capture a moment, doing B&W, abusing DOF, post-processing.  Are those technical things?  Artistic? Both?  What's the problem he's trying to solve?  Is it just a bit of a rant?

On the other hand, this question

[Is technical perfection necessary for an artistically awe-inspiring photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16217/is-technical-perfection-necessary-for-an-artistically-awe-inspiring-photograph)

asks a very specific question, even giving specific examples of what he considers the artistic side of things vs technical (defects in this case).

I think that question covers the same ground, probably a duplicate even.  If you disagree, then I'd leave this question closed and pen your own question that targets what the above question didn't.

Sorry, maybe it's just me, but I read that question and I just can't tell what he's exactly talking about.  Then you ask a good question (albeit too broad probably) but all that lead-in to the question really muddles it in my mind.  Great topic, but worst possible question formation possible IMO.

Comment: It's similar to the question you link, but I think different because it focuses on the photographer rather than the result. If this one doesn't get the reopen votes, I'm try to re-ask it as a more clear new question.

Comment: So "What can a person with hopeless technical ability do to produce good/artistic photographs?"

Comment: MikeW, that sounds a bit like [what are your easiest beginner tips](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips), doesn't it?

Comment: @EsaPaulasto I think it's not so much a beginner question, as it is about someone who thinks it's beyond their abilities to ever master all the technical stuff - is it really necessary or can they still make good images?

Comment: I was thinking the words _"What can a person ... do to produce good/artistic photographs?"_ and I think the beginner tips is one way to address the question. The question if technical skills is needed to make good images is another question, and of course more to the topic of this Q&A right here. :)

Comment: that beginner question does have a lot of good non-technical stuff

Answer (score 0):

I read and reread the question, and it does look like rambling, hard to understand what is the question. Trying to look behind the words into what the between-the-lines-question might be, but I fail to find anything that I could answer. But, I can still relate to his text quite well, as I am one of those who know something about tech and theory of photography but I can't produce a good photo that would say anything to anybody.

My solution is to *humbly accept the fact* that I do not have the artistic eye nor talent to produce awesome photography. But in the question it looks like it is about the unfairness of digital era, where unskilled people are taking artistic looking photos without effort or even knowing what it is they do. How can one answer to that?

So, yes I would vote for re-opening, if I could. Just for my curiousity to see what kind of answers can there be. Can't really judge a question unanswerable on the grounds that I myself can not think of any suitable answer. And for this Q&A site it is the answers that matter the most, while questions are really there only to help the search engine find you those answers that you are looking for.